# main method not executed with App in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.12

Hi I'm new to scala and trying to use scala 2.12.10 for a project. I'm trying to follow along with [this tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/building-a-scala-project-with-intellij-and-sbt.html#) which is written for the latest version of scala and I've gotten it to work fine (the print statement prints to sbt shell as expected). But when I try to do this in 2.12.10, it seems to run successfully but does not print anything. I found a post suggesting to run `Console.out.flush` after the print statements but this did not work for me. Any thoughts on how to get the print statements to render. If you try to implement the tutorial, I had to adjust the object to the following so that it would run:

```scala
package example

object Main extends App {
  def main(): Unit = {
    println("here")
    val ages: Seq[Int] = Seq(42, 61, 29, 64)
    println("here ")
    //println(s"The oldest person is ${ages.max}")
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if adding `extends App` is screwing this up but it was the only thing that worked to get it to run without throwing an error.

Comment: Remove the `App` and change `main` to `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {` and then `run` again.

Comment: In the tutorial `@main def run() = ...`  is a Scala 3 thing https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/hello-world-1.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-hello-world.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a `scala` app to be runnable you either need an object that has a method with following signature:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit
```

or the object needs to extends the `App` trait.

But not both.